# How to loop through static constatns of a struct?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, static

I am using R.swift to get the names of assets. I am creating a library for checking asset duplicates and want to iterate through all asset names to fetch data for checking the duplicacy of assets.How can i iterate through statics in swift.

```
struct image {
  static let winnerPunyaOrang = Rswift.ImageResource(bundle: R.hostingBundle, name: "Winner Punya Orang")
  static let fire_ico = Rswift.ImageResource(bundle: R.hostingBundle, name: "fire_ico")
  static let fire = Rswift.ImageResource(bundle: R.hostingBundle, name: "fire")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your solution:

1. You can't enumerate all images without having to create and
   maintain an array of all the values (which you don't want to do).
2. The fact that you're allocating images to static variables will create a lot of memory overhead for your program, this will be particularly bad if these are large images or there are a lot of them.

A much better approach would be to use a `CaseIterable` enumeration. This will allow for code extensibility in the future using a pattern that won't result in memory overhead and with minimal maintenance.

```
enum ImageAsset: String, CaseIterable {

  //your cases go here...
  case winnerPunyaOrang = "Winner Punya Orang"
  case fireIco = "fire_ico"
  //... and you can continuously extend them by adding more asset names

  //This function will return images as and when you need them
  func image() -> UIImage {
    return Rswift.ImageResource(bundle: R.hostingBundle, name: self.rawValue)
  }
}
```

Now whenever you need an image asset in the program you can just call:

```
let image = ImageAsset.fireIco.image()
```

Comment: I am running a script given by https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift to automate this process.So can i automate the above